# How to publish event of a none AggregateRoot object?

Tags: domain-driven-design, nestjs, cqrs, event-sourcing

So I am using **NestJs** with **CQRS** and **DDD** in a **microservices** environment with Eventstore and MySql as a database. In NestJS in order to publish an event, the object needs to be of type `AggregateRoot`. So I am publishing the object returned after saving it to the database in such way that it is of type `AggregateRoot`.

What I need to do now is just publish an incoming request as-is in an `Event` and other services will listen to that event without the need for it to be of type `AggregateRoot`.

**Example**: I have an incoming `Order` to the `Order-Microservice` containing objects needed in other microservices (like `Delivery-Microservice` and `Assembly-Microservice`). I don't need to save it in the order-ms to be able to publish it, because it contains data that I don't necessarily need in the order-ms.

The NestJs `EventPublisher` requires an object to be of type `AggregateRoot`. How should I publish that event to EventStore?

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't always require AggregateRoot.
[image]

Comment: thank you, but now am getting this error and i can't seem to know how to fix it {error: Bad request: Could not unwrap network package for command WriteEvents.}

Comment: It's hard to help with so little information. But  I think that the bad request is not related to CQRS and EventBus.

Comment: i couldn't find anything helpful online this is my event { this._eventBus.publish(new OrderRequestedEvent(requestOrderDto))} and at the event handler am getting the same type in constructor , in every other event publishing when i use mergeObjectContext with commit() it works fine but if i try and switch using eventBus it doesn't work

Comment: Could you provide your event handler? And prof that the exception appears from the handler?

Comment: import { Logger } from '@nestjs/common';
import { IEventHandler, EventsHandler } from '@nestjs/cqrs';
import { OrderRequestedEvent } from '../../impl/order/order-requested.event';


@EventsHandler(OrderRequestedEvent)
export class OrderRequestedHandler implements IEventHandler<OrderRequestedEvent> {
    handle(event: OrderRequestedEvent) {
        Logger.log(event, 'OrderRequestedEvent'); // write here
    }
}

Comment: Definitely there is nothing broken it this code. What is "write here"? The exception looks like some trouble on the connection between services

Comment: is there any other place where i should import EventBus other than the constructor of the command ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210291/discussion-between-maciej-sikorski-and-abdessalem-letaief).

Answer (score 0):

It is true that you can trigger events from different locations (as @maciej-sikorski [mentions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60826547/8295283) in his reference to the [NestJS documentation](https://docs.nestjs.com/recipes/cqrs#events).

But you have to be careful here, as doing this can easily break common DDD / CQRS concepts and best-practices. In general:

- `Command` changes state conceptually in an `AggregateRoot`, and `Event` represents this state.
- `AggregateRoot` serves as public entrypoint (i.e. 'public API') of your Orders bounded context.
- Events are part of the domain, and should be related to the aggregate root, once it is committed.

So don't emit Events anywhere outside your domain objects. But it is okay to e.g. apply a `DeliveryAddressValidated` event to the aggregate root from a value object called `DeliveryAddress` that ensures all address fields are filled in, and the address exists. Upon committing the `Order` aggregate root - when the aggregate is in a consistent state - this event *could* be picked up in the `Delivery-Microservice`.

Alternatively - given your `Order` receives information it does not need - you could have a look at rearranging your bounded contexts. I don't know your design, but sticking with Delivery domain, you could have a `Saga` that waits for `OrderRequested` event (indicating Order is valid, but delivery address data + validation is not part of this process) and then triggers a `DeliverOrder` command (or e.g. a `ValidateDelivery` command) to the `Delivery-Microservice`.